# Phantom hard drive after deploying latest Windows 7 image from WDS

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-explorer, deployment, wds

Receiving a new batch of PCs prompted us to recapture our WDS image for our on-site Windows 7 machines. Rolled into the new image (i.e. the only changes that have been made since the previous version of the image) was the suite of drivers, Adobe Reader upgraded from 9.13 to 10.0 and the exclusion of Microsoft Access.

When we deploy this image to a PC we now get two hard drives appearing in Explorer.

[image: Windows 7 Explorer]

This second disk, when viewing the properties, is an exact clone of the "real" hard drive (these machines only have one installed). This phantom drive is full of what looks like temp/log/cache files.

[image: Windows 7 Explorer - Z Drive]

**Edit:** Disk Management shows only one disk assigned one drive letter.

[image: Windows 7 Explorer - Disk Management]

We have tried uninstalling Adobe after deployment, but the problem persists. Is there any way to remove this drive (so our users don't try storing documents in there thinking they have a second drive installed)?

Comment: How about a screenshot of your disk manager. That would possibly really help.

Comment: @KCotreau, screenshot of disk manager added, including drive letter assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a command-prompt (`cmd.exe`) and run `subst`; you should see something like the following:

```
C:\>subst
Z:\: => C:\Users\JOSHUAK\AppData\Local\Temp

C:\>
```

It means that the drive letter ‘Z’ is mapped to your temp directory (it might be the system temp directory `C:\Windows\Temp` instead of your user temp directory `C:\Users\JOSHUAK\AppData\Local\Temp`).

You can delete the mapping as follows.

```
C:\subst z: /d
```

Your next task is to figure out where the mapping is being done. Try a tool like [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902).

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: To anyone interested, the cause was the latest version of UniPrint (which had been updated on existing PCs, but freshly installed for the new image.)

Comment: Are you saying that UniPrint adds a subst? That sounds pretty odd and unlikely (and as a programmer, I have to say kind of lazy, if true).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it wasn't intentional. But to stop the automatic mapping we had to add "DriveMapping"="0" into [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\UniPrint\Client] (http://communities.uniprint.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=60)

Comment: Really? That worked? There wasn’t a batch-file or `Run` reg-entry or other startup item doing it? If the only change required was indeed that one, UniPrint-related key, then it sounds like it was indeed doing it on purpose. There are better, more proper ways to map drives; `subst` is a user tool (granted, apps *can* use it, but it’s lazy, *particularly* for a **commercial** program).

Comment: The above reg key may work on UniPrint 4 but for UniPrint 5 you need this: [HKLM\SOFTWARE\UniPrint\Client], new DWORD "DisableVirtualDrive" set to "1"

Answer (score 1):

I just want to clarify, since use of ***subst*** is not recommended and many folks will not understand the difference between a mapped drive and a subst.

Subst does not ***map*** a drive. That is done with net.exe and refers to assigning a drive letter to a ***network*** drive. Subst basically creates an "alias" (that's not the technically correct term) for a path on an existing drive. You can subst to a mapped drive. For instance, you can map (using net.exe) a network drive as drive K:\, create K:\MyStuff and then subst M: K:\MyStuff.

As mentioned, although subst still exists and works fine, use of that is generally discouraged.