# Where do these fake drive references come from?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Phantom hard drive after deploying latest Windows 7 image from WDS](https://superuser.com/questions/317928/phantom-hard-drive-after-deploying-latest-windows-7-image-from-wds)

This is a really weird issue which is the reason for the vague title; sorry.

The following screenshot shows a few local disks on my machine.  The only problem is I only have one disk and it is correctly represented by C:.
[image: local disks]

Disk Management shows no problems.  The "fake" local drives are pointing at My Documents.  They're labeled W: and X:.  There's also a Y: that shows up in the sidebar with a question mark (left sidebar in the screenshot above Freehold).

What is going on here and how do I fix it?  I've never seen anything like this.

Comment: Are you a member of a windows SBS domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `W:` and `X:` drive letters might be mapped using *DefineDosDevice()*, which can be controlled using `subst` from command line. (`subst` has been a common way to map a directory to a drive letter since MS-DOS times.)

Run `subst` to list the mappings; use `subst /d w:` to delete them.

---

`Y:` might be caused by a similar mapping to a non-existent location, in which case `subst /d y:` would remove it as described above.

But there can be other causes for it; for example, on my own system I've had a new iTunes component (APSDaemon) freeze leaving such an "unknown" drive in place of sister's iPod. There could also be other, even more unlikely reasons.

---

If you want to dig deep, [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657) would show what each drive letter points to. In the tree displayed, global devices are under `\GLOBAL??`, while local devices for each logon session are under `\Sessions\sid\DosDevices\luid`. You might be able to track them back to weird device drivers or such.

[image: WinObj] [image: WinObj]

<sup>(Please excuse the lack of freehand circles.)</sup>

Comment: +1. The fact that the drive sizes are identical suggests they are all the same drive. SUBST it is.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks.  Now that I understand what it is I can guess at the cause.  I think an app called PureSync caused the issue when I tried to sync a mapped network drive folder to a local drive folder.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you see a bunch of identical disk (that are not part of a RAID), the most likely cause is `subst`.

1. Open a command-prompt (`cmd.exe`)
2. Type `subst` to see a list of mappings
3. Type `subst w: /d` and `subst x: /d` to delete them

Of course if you did not do it yourself (as your question seems to imply), then the question becomes [how, where, and when did they get mapped](https://superuser.com/questions/317928/).