# Phantom hard drive that cannot be removed

Tags: windows

I am experiencing an issue similar to [Phantom hard drive after deploying latest Windows 7 image from WDS](https://superuser.com/questions/317928/phantom-hard-drive-after-deploying-latest-windows-7-image-from-wds?s=bb038733-9621-4d5d-9e0d-8add0a06405d#new-answer).

I tried adding the registry value

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\UniPrint\DriveMapping = 0
```

and then rebooting, but I still have a phantom Z drive showing up. I also tried deleting the Preferred Virtual Drive, but it just came back.

What could be causing this?

Comment: here is the fix from uniprint, http://communities.uniprint.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1098. Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\UniPrint\Client]
"DisableVirtualDrive"=dword:00000001

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that tool, but you can try using this [DriveCleanup tool](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/drivetools_e.html) to remove the phantom drive.

It's able to remove virtual drives I've created with Daemon Tools, so it might do the job for you.

> DriveCleanup removes all currently non present "Storage Volumes",
>   "Disk", "CDROM", "Floppy" USB drives and their USB devices from the
>   device tree. Furthermore it removes orphaned registry items related to
>   these device types. Since V0.8 it removes WPD devices under Vista and
>   Win7.
>
> Started with parameter -T (like test) it shows which devices it would
>   remove.
>
> DriveCleanup -T
>
> Started without a parameter, it does its job without further inquiry.
>   To remove certain types of devices there are the parameters -U -D -C
>   -F -V -W and -R.
>
> Sample to remove abandoned registry entries only: drivecleanup -R
>
> Under x64 editions of Windows only the included x64 version works
>   correctly, with the Win32 version you will see "severity error 0x235",
>   which is ERROR_IN_WOW64.
>
> Admin privileges required.