# Windows showing up new unknown (Z:) drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, windows-8.1

Recently, a new drive with letter **Z** showing up which cannot be opened to see what's inside. Here is the picture for better understanding.

[image: screenshot]

How to fix it? Sometimes, restarting system fixes temporarily.

**Right click** menu:

[image: right click on drive shows up this]

Disk Management view:

It shows the unknown drive without the drive letter and says it is EFI something. It again says it is empty but right click on drive shows it is not empty. Am just guessing with the drive size. So, it could be different drive too. Please look at the following picture for understanding.

[image: disk management view of my HDD]

P.S. I have upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1

Comment: If you right-click it and select Properties, what does it tell you about it?

Comment: Updated question. It says it is Fat32 drive. @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007

Answer (score 3):

Courtesy of [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/4579b83c-3ca6-444d-93cd-9c9f45a36dc0/mapping-the-volume-guid-to-the-physical-disk-and-partion-im-stuck?forum=ITCG) on the Microsoft Technet Forums, I found the following Powershell solution:

> ```
> $CimPartInfo = get-partition 
> foreach ($CimPart in $CimPartInfo) {
>     if ($CimPart.Guid -eq $null) {
>         $PartGUID = [regex]::match($CimPart.AccessPaths, 'Volume({[^}]+})').Groups[1].Value
>     }
>     else {
>         $PartGUID = $CimPart.Guid
>     }
>     "Volume GUID $PartGUID"
>     "`tDisk #     :`t$($CimPart.DiskNumber)"
>     "`tPartition #:`t$($CimPart.PartitionNumber)"
>     "`tDriveLetter:`t$($CimPart.DriveLetter)"
> } #foreach CimPart
> ```

It’ll print something likes this:

```
Volume GUID {6c747513-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}
        Disk #     :    0
        Partition #:    1
        DriveLetter:
Volume GUID {6c747513-0000-0000-0000-f01500000000}
        Disk #     :    0
        Partition #:    2
        DriveLetter:    C
Volume GUID
        Disk #     :    0
        Partition #:    0
        DriveLetter:
Volume GUID {6c747513-0000-0000-0000-20023b000000}
        Disk #     :    0
        Partition #:    4
        DriveLetter:    U
Volume GUID {6c747513-0000-0000-0000-20823b000000}
        Disk #     :    0
        Partition #:    3
        DriveLetter:
```

You can also cross-reference the GUID with the output of `mountvol Z: /L` to verify.

In your case it is most likely the [EFI System Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition). On UEFI installations, it contains the Windows Boot Manager and its BCD (Boot Configuration Data) store – by default, at least.

You can remove the drive letter like this:

```
mountvol z: /d
```

You can read more about the `mountvol` command [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772586(v=ws.12).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. For now, I went with Reset option. Surely, will give this a try next time if the problem arises again and check that solves permanently.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a recovery, UEFI or other partition which is normally hidden in Windows. To check, press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> and enter *disk management*.  Select the *Windows Disk Management* console and see if that ~256 MB partition is near the beginning -- if so, it's likely for UEFI data.

[image: Windows Disk Management scan]

For more complete information, try a third-party tool such as [MiniTool Partition Wizard Free](https://www.partitionwizard.com/).

[image: MiniTool Partition Wizard Free scan]

If it is just a system partition, you can safely ignore Z: or you can unmount or hide it.

Comment: Updated question with disk management screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the drive ended up being a `subst`, which associates a path with a drive letter. This command has actually been around since MS-DOS.

> Open a command-prompt (cmd.exe) and run `subst`; you should see something like the following:
>
> ```
> C:\>subst
> Z:\: => C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp
>
> C:\>
> ```
>
> It means that the drive letter ‘Z’ is mapped to your temp directory (it might be the system temp directory `C:\Windows\Temp` instead of your user temp directory `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp`).
>
> You can delete the mapping as follows:
>
> ```
> C:\subst z: /d
> ```

Quoted text from

- [Phantom hard drive after deploying latest Windows 7 image from WDS](https://superuser.com/questions/317928/phantom-hard-drive-after-deploying-latest-windows-7-image-from-wds)